# .NET Core WebApp Authentication via Azure AD but extract data from database

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, web-applications, azure-active-directory

I am creating a .NET Core WebApp with authentication via AzureAD (SO I can login to the application and I can see the logged in User information). Now, we also have a database with a lot of data, but most importantly the roles, assigned to an user.

My question is, how can I keep the Login via AzureAD and then extract all the data, that I need from the database while authenticating and store the user's role (or whatever data) as a Claim in Microsoft Identity? Is there any way to override the login method or how should I do this?

So:

1. Login Via AzureAD
2. Get the Email address from the logged in user
3. Extract the user's data from a database (with the email address)
4. Store the user's data as Claims in the application
5. Proceed to the application

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is shown in [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59572399/5751404) . The only thing not mentioned is to get the  email address in `OnTokenValidated` method , you can get email like :

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
        {

            //get the user's email 
            var email = ctx.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;

            //query the database to get the role

            // add claims
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
            };
            var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

            ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much already! How can I access my DBContext from there ? I register it above this code snippet.

Comment: @bbrinck , try :  `var db = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();`