# .NET Core add Claim after AzuerAD Authentication

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, claims-based-identity, microsoft-identity-platform

My application signs in via AzureAD, but now I need to get information from the DB and then store the Role as a Claim.

So my question is: How can I store the Role as Claim after authentication ?

This is what I tried:

```
var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
var identity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
```

But when I go to another controller, the claim does not exist anymore ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that during the authentication , in OIDC middleware , `OnTokenValidated`offers you the chance to modify the ClaimsIdentity obtained from the incoming token , code below is for your reference :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));


services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
        {
            //query the database to get the role

            // add claims
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
            };
            var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

            ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
    };
});
```

Then in controller , you can get the claim like :

```
var role = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value;
```

Comment: Thank you so much already! How can I access my DBContext from there ? I register it above this code snippet.

Comment: @bbrinck , try :  `var db = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();`

Comment: Can you also signout in OICD Middleware - For Example, when the signed in user does not exist in my database or if the Role for the User is not set yet?

Comment: Or can you abort the login and return to the login window somehow ?

Comment: You can use middleware or action filter or policy to check the users/roles claim , if null , redirect user to logout action . It's odd to set your logic in jwt events since user is correctly authenticated from Azure AD .

Comment: Ok and how can I do it in Middleware? The thing is, the user should not have access to the app, when he is not registered in our database.

Comment: I see, that if i add .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role) it gives me access denied, but can I change the ReturnUrl of this somehow, so that it returns to the login ?

AzureAD/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FHome

Comment: Access denied but authentication pass , you can use asp.net core identity with Azure AD , So that in external login callback function , asp.net core identity will automatically check whether user is in your local database: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54880889/5751404

Comment: set `"CookieSchemeName": "Identity.External"` if using asp.net core identity with azure ad

Comment: Do you have any good tutorial for this ? I am new to this and I do not understand what you mean with this ... :/

Comment: let me clarify : If using asp.net core identity with Azure AD as external identity provider . After login using AAD , asp.net identity will help creating a local user , user can input his AAD email so that in database you can know which local user is associated with specific Azure AD user . You can then implement custom logic like authorization in local database . You can try the steps to test the scenario to check whether it meet your requirement :https://stackoverflow.com/a/54880889/5751404

Comment: Ok, got it. But, just to know: Could I somehow cancel the login, when the user is not registered in the DB, by using OIDC Middleware? For example in OnTokenValidated Event ?

Comment: @NanYu, any reason you're not adding the claim to the first claims identity instead of creating a second one?

Answer (score 0):

In `OnTokenValidated` event, you can throw specific exception when user does not exists your database. and then `OnRemoteFailure` event redirect user to specific action method for that particular exception

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                 {
                     OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                     {
                         
                         // get email claim
                         var emailClaim = context.Principal.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
                         
                         UserEntity cu = null;

                         using (var accountService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IAccountService>())
                         {
                             cu = await accountService.Authorize(emailClaim.Value);
                         }

                         if (cu == null)
                         {
                             throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(string.Format("Could not find user for login '{0}' ", emailClaim.Value));
                         }

                         
                         var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Principal.Identity.AuthenticationType);                         
                          
                         // keep the id_token for logout 
                         newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                         // add email claim
                         newIdentity.AddClaim(emailClaim);
                         
                         // add email value as name claim
                         newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, emailClaim.Value));                         

                         // add other claims here like roles                         
                         
                         context.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
                         context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(3);

                         // overwrite existing authentication ticket
                         context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(newIdentity);
                     },                     
                     OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
                     {
                         var idTokenHint = context.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirst("id_token");
                         if (idTokenHint != null)
                             context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;                         
                         await Task.FromResult(0);
                     },
                     OnRemoteFailure = async context =>
                     {
                         if (context.Failure is UnauthorizedAccessException)
                         {
                             context.Response.Redirect("/Account/UnAuthorized");
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Error");
                         }
                         context.HandleResponse();
                         await Task.FromResult(0);
                     }
                 };
```

**AccontController.cs**

```
   public class AccountController : Controller
   {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult UnAuthorized()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.Clear();
            await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(HttpContext, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(HttpContext, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
   }
```